# ¿Qué es un Handler?

Tags: python

La pregunta es sencilla, que se entiende por **Handler**. Sé que en inglés *Handler* es una especie de *Manejador*. Pero no logro entender el concepto que conlleva, si sigue algún patrón de diseño o alguna cosa por el estilo. Si es síncrono o asíncrono, etc.

Mi pregunta surge de utilizar el *logging* de *Python*. En el cual se pueden configurar varios *Handlers* para mandar los logs a diferentes sitios.

```
'handlers': {
        'wsgi': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'stream': 'ext://flask.logging.wsgi_errors_stream',
            'formatter': 'default'
        },
        'info_file_handler': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': 'logs/info.log',
            'formatter': 'default',
            'maxBytes': 485760,
            'backupCount': 5,
            'encoding': 'utf8'
        }
```

Si alguien tiene una buena explicación y ejemplo bienvenido sea. No hay ninguna etiqueta sobre handler (y no puedo crearla por mi baja reputación).

Comment: En general, en los lenguajes de programación un handler es el encargado de recibir datos, manejarlos y realizar una acción como respuesta. Por ejemplo, hay handlers de eventos, que entran en acción cuando se produce un evento registrado en el código(Por ejemplo, si algún usuario da click a un botón), handlers de memoria, que realizan procesos en la memoria... Etc.

Comment: ¿Has comprobado la siguiente pregunta? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195357/what-is-a-handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un `Handler` es un concepto bastante ambiguo en el sentido que no hay una definición univoca de lo que es, ni de como debe construirse, solo hablando de **Python**, en la documentación no hay una definición precisa y el término `Handler` se usa en muchas clases y objetos sin llegar a concretar un patrón único, a lo sumo podremos llegar a generalizar lo que ya sabes, que un `Handler` es un "manejador", algo que es capaz de "recibir" un evento, un mensaje, etc y actuar en función al mismo.

Pero en el contexto del módulo `logging` podemos llegar a especificar un poco más de lo que se trata un `Handler`, veamos primero como funciona un logeo de información:

- Por empezar todo parte de un `Logger`, un objeto con el cual podremos definir  múltiples mensajes a "logear" durante la ejecución de nuestros scripts.
- Cuando necesitamos registrar un mensaje, usaremos cualquiera de las rutinas del objeto, por ej: `warning()`, `error()`, `log()` etc. Todas ellas terminan invocando a una función interna `_log()`.
- `_log()` construye el "registro" que deseamos guardar y por último invoca al método `callHandlers()`.
- `callHandlers()`, como su nombre lo indica itera por la lista de `Handlers` configurada previamente e invoca para cada una de las instancias de los mismos, el metódo `handle()`.

Es importante notar que con el `Logger` nos abstraemos del "dónde" y el "como" se registraran los mensajes, para eso es que tenemos los `Handler`, con algunas características:

- Es un objeto que hereda de la clase base [`logging.Handler`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/logging/__init__.py)
- [`logging.Handler`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/logging/__init__.py) tiene un método fundamental que es `handle()`, todos los `Handlers` heredan este método, el cual termina invocando a otro, no implementado en esta clase llamado `emit()`.
- `emit()` es el método que debería implementar cada `Handler` heredado de [`logging.Handler`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/logging/__init__.py) y que encapsula la lógica final para tratar el registro de log, para guardarlo en un determinado archivo, para enviarlo por la red, para registrarlo como evento del sistema, etc. `emit()` y el `Handler` en definitiva, son los que manejan el "dónde" y el "como" se registrarán los mensajes.

Con este contexto podríamos decir que un `Handler` es un objeto que se encarga de una tarea especifica, que posee además una interface determinada, para ser invocada por un objeto jerarquicamente superior que "delega" en él, parte del trabajo ya sea por un motivo de delegación de responsabilidades o para favorecer la extensibilidad funcional.

A modo de ejemplo, agrego la definición del `Handler` más básico y elemental el `NullHandler`:

```
class NullHandler(Handler):
    """
    This handler does nothing. It's intended to be used to avoid the
    "No handlers could be found for logger XXX" one-off warning. This is
    important for library code, which may contain code to log events. If a user
    of the library does not configure logging, the one-off warning might be
    produced; to avoid this, the library developer simply needs to instantiate
    a NullHandler and add it to the top-level logger of the library module or
    package.
    """
    def handle(self, record):
        """Stub."""

    def emit(self, record):
        """Stub."""

    def createLock(self):
        self.lock = None
```

Puedes ver que solo se definen (en blanco) los métodos antes mencionados `handle()` y  `emit()`. Nota:  `createLock()` es para re-definir el mecanismo de lockeo estándar de `Handler` ya que en este caso no se necesita lockeo de ninguna clase.